# Lockscreen controls for ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

How can an ionic app running in the background be controlled on the lockscreen similar to basic audio control in android/ios?

I see the cordova-plugin-background-mode for running the app in the background. But how to control the app on the lockscreen?

Interactive notifications won't work for my use case, which involves long intervals between user interaction, similar to how a user interacts with a music player (I'm trying to avoid the user having to unlock their screen every time).

I don't see any related solutions...

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: This works https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/music-controls/ but not for Mi Ui :(